# Javascript multiplying strings

Tags: javascript, algorithm, biginteger

I was doing following leetcode [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/multiply-strings/) on multiplying

```
Given two non-negative integers num1 and num2 represented as strings, return the
product of num1 and num2, also represented as a string.

Note: You must not use any built-in BigInteger library or convert the inputs to
integer directly.

Example 1:

Input: num1 = "2", num2 = "3" 
Output: "6"

Example 2:

Input: num1 = "123", num2 = "456" 
Output: "56088"

Constraints:

- 1 <= num1.length, num2.length <= 200
- num1 and num2 consist of digits only.
- Both num1 and num2 do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.
```

For this used the following approach

1. Convert the string to int
2. Multiply the int

Algo for the same is

```
const numberMap = {
    "0": 0,
    "1": 1, 
    "2": 2,
    "3": 3, 
    "4": 4,
    "5": 5,
    "6": 6,
    "7": 7, 
    "8": 8, 
    "9": 9
}
var multiply = function(num1, num2) {
    let i = num1.length
    let j = num2.length 
    let sum = currentPower = 0
    let firstNumber = secondNumber = 0
    while(i > 0 || j > 0) {
        // if I or J is equal to zero, means we have iterated hence we will set the value to one 
        const firstNum = i > 0 ? (numberMap[num1[i-1]]) * (10**currentPower) : 0
        const secondNum = j > 0 ? (numberMap[num2[j-1]]) * (10**currentPower) : 0 
        firstNumber += firstNum
        secondNumber += secondNum
        currentPower++
        i--
        j--
    }

    sum = firstNumber * secondNumber
    return sum.toString()
 };
```

but when the following input is given

```
"123456789"
"987654321"
```

it yields the following output `"121932631112635260"` instead of `"121932631112635269"`

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could multiply each digit with each other digit and take the indices as position.

> Like you would do by hand, like
>
> ```
> 1  2  3  4  *  4  3  2  1
> -------------------------
>                1  2  3  4
>             1  4  6  8
>          3  6  9 12
>       4  8 12 16
> -------------------------
>       5  3  2  2  1  1  4
> ```

This approach uses the reversed arrays of the strings and reverse the result set as well.

Before retuning the result, the array is filterd by the leading zeros.

```js
function multiply(a, b) {
    var aa = [...a].reverse(),
        bb = [...b].reverse(),
        p = [],
        i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < bb.length; j++) {
            if (!p[i + j]) p[i + j] = 0;
            p[i + j] += aa[i] * bb[j];
            if (p[i + j] > 9) {
                if (!p[i + j + 1]) p[i + j + 1] = 0;
                p[i + j + 1] += Math.floor(p[i + j] / 10);
                p[i + j] %= 10;
            }
        }
    }
    return p
        .reverse()
        .filter((valid => (v, i, { length }) => valid = +v || valid || i + 1 === length)(false))
        .join('');
}

console.log(multiply('2', '3'));     //     6
console.log(multiply('123', '456')); // 56088
console.log(multiply('9133', '0'));  //     0
console.log(multiply('9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999', '9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999'));
```

Comment: Can you explain the algo as well

Answer (score 1):

```js
function multiply() {
    var str = document.getElementById('a').value;
    var str1 = document.getElementById('b').value;
    var l = str.length;
    var l1 = str1.length;
    var list = [];
    var prod = 0;
    var cur = 0;

    list.length = l + l1;
    // store 0 to to all list elements
    list.fill(0);

    // access string in reverse
    for (var i = l - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (
            var j = l1 - 1;
            j >= 0;
            j-- // access string in reverse
        ) {
            // ASCII value of character and - ("0") ASCII Value 48
            prod = (str.charCodeAt(i) - 48) * (str1.charCodeAt(j) - 48); 
            cur = list[i + j + 1] + prod;
            list[i + j + 1] = cur % 10;
            list[i + j] += parseInt(cur / 10);
        }
    }

    var res = '';
    res = list.join('');
    if (res[0] == 0) {
        // if First Char ==0 then remove
        res = res.slice(1); 
    }
    console.log(res);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var multiply = function(num1, num2) {
   let v1=BigInt(num1)
   let v2=BigInt(num2)
   let v3=v1*v2
   return v3.toString()
};
```

Comment: It's better to explain your solution a little bit.

Comment: Here the code convert the input string into BigInt which can hold 2^53-1. After that multiply the two converted string and assign it to a variable and convert that varible to string and return to the function.

Answer (score -3):

Just convert to Numbers, multiply, and then convert back to a string.

```
function mult(a, b){
    return (Number(a) * Number(b)).toString();
}
```

In JavaScript, ints are not a specific type. They're the number type. We could use the parseInt() function instead of the Number() function to convert, but we know we're receiving an int as an input anyway, so there's no need for that kind of parsing.

Comment: mult("9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999", "9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999") returns "9.999999999999999e+217"

Comment: right, but you don't get **all** digits of the product. (please see my answer ...)

Comment: Converting to number will work for small digits. To make it work for longer number we should use BigInt, refer my solution